# Is there an easy way to create particles and destroy them in an unequal periods of time?

Tags: particles

I need to make all particles to appear at once and disappear gradually.

To appear at once, I set the **start** and **end** values to be the same.

But they all disappear at once too because of the **lifetime** value. I think this input value should be replaced with two values so that we can specify the exit or dissolve time of a particle system.

Comment: you can create multiple particle systems with high randomization values and keep the lifetimes different

Comment: you can also change the lifetime random value